# Python parsing numbers

Tags: python-2.7

hi im new in python and trying to parse a file which has thousands of lines like these

> gi162312575refNC0034243   ABCC    Z_DNA_Motif 13204   13213   .   +   .   ID=gi162312575refNC0034243_13204_13213_ZDNA;length=10;score=35;composition=2A/3C/3G/1T;sequence=gcacacgtgt;subset=1
>
> gi162312575refNC0034243   ABCC    Z_DNA_Motif 26389   26398   .   +   .   ID=gi162312575refNC0034243_26389_26398_ZDNA;length=10;score=35;composition=0A/1C/5G/3T;sequence=gtgtgcgtgt;subset=1

I am trying to parse the numbers at the upper right corner so i can parse another file(string[13204:13213]...) but i couldnt get the numbers.How can i get them?

Comment: A typo: What 'have' you tried?

Comment: I tried to take away all the letters first to make it more simple then realized its a waste of time,then tried to parse between 'Motif' and '+' but couldnt do it

Comment: Looks like @Silas was faster :)

Comment: Well thank you too for your time:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format is the same for all the strings, you can split them on whitespace and take element 3 and 4

```
string.split()[3:5]
```

Comment: Thanks a million!Although i dont know the split function very well it should be string.split()[3:5] to get all the numbers.But thanks again for your time

Comment: @user3130887 Yes, you are right, I fixed it. In general when you specify a range in python it is half-open interval [a;b).